# how to fill one column with desired values and other column with 0 in R

Tags: r

I have a data frame (c0) that contains some columns and one row

```
>c0
Sample_Name  Chr_No   Frequence
0             0       0
```

I have one variable (allchr) that contain 22 chromosome names. I want to add allchr name to c0$Chr_No and other columns as 0. Is there is a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
c1= data.frame(Chr_No=allchr,
Sample_Name=rep(0,length(allchr)),
Frequence=rep(0,length(allchr)),
stringAsFactors=FALSE)
```

If you want to keep the first row use `rbind(c0,c1)`